# How do I fix floating CSS label always being active showing 'invalid input' in my form?

Tags: html, css, label, floating

I am trying to get my survey form questions to have floating labels that are still visible when the user is inputting data, and after adding email validation with an error message, the second question is broken. It shows as being always invalid, even with no input.

I have tried changing the CSS selector to an adjacent sibling combinator, but while this gets my label in the correct place initially, it breaks the specific `input[type="email"]:invalid ~.question-label` styling.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-option">
    <input type="email" id="email" class="question-answer" placeholder=" " required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label class="question-label" id="email-label">Email<span class="asterisk"> *</span></label>
    <div class="requirements">
      Must be a valid email address
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.question-answer:focus ~.question-label, .question-answer:valid ~.question-label {
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 14px;
     color: #4285f4;
}
input[type="email"]:valid + label {
  opacity: 0;
}
.requirements {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
input[type="email"]:invalid {
    background-color: pink;
    transition: ease .25s;
}

input[type="email"]:invalid ~.question-label {
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
input[type="email"]:invalid:focus ~.requirements {
    opacity: 100;
    display: block;
}
```

There is a full Codepen here: https://codepen.io/Pixel123/pen/NzByep if the issue needs clarification.

I am wanting for the labels to be in one starting position, then to move up and resize once focused on, and turn blue once a valid email has been entered (this part works). If input is not a valid email, the `div` that states *Must be a valid email address* becomes visible.

As it stands, the input highlighting that should only show on invalid emails is always on, and highlighting the field when there is no input.

Comment: I've added an answer that covers your case for the empty e-mail field; however, you'll have to elaborate on what you mean by labels moving up and resizing when focused on; which labels in particular?

Comment: Apologies on the confusion! I want the email label to move upwards and resize, and if the input is invalid, to change to red while maintaining the smaller size and position, and highlight the invalid input field even while not focused. When focused on, the `requirements` div should be visible. Your empty email field answer works, but when there is input in the field, the label is now over the input. Let me know if that's not clear enough! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `:empty` selector and set the background color to your chosen color; in the case of your pen this is white:

```
.question-answer:empty {
  background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

To cover the case where the label isn't transitioning like the rest; follow the same idea by using `:not:empty` where you set the `input[type="email"]:invalid`.

---

Below is a working example; take note of the use of `:empty` on `question-answer`.

```css
    .question-answer:focus ~.question-label, .question-answer:valid ~.question-label {
        top: -16px;
        font-size: 14px;
         color: #4285f4;
    }
    .question-answer:empty {
      background-color: #FFF !important;
    }
    input[type="email"]:valid + label {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .requirements {
      padding-top: 5px;
      font-style: italic;
      color: red;
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
    }
    input[type="email"]:invalid {
        background-color: pink;
        transition: ease .25s;
    }

    input[type="email"]:invalid:not:empty ~.question-label {
      top: -16px;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: red;
    }
    input[type="email"]:invalid:focus ~.requirements {
        opacity: 100;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="form-option">
        <input type="email" id="email" class="question-answer" placeholder=" " required>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label class="question-label" id="email-label">Email<span class="asterisk"> *</span></label>
        <div class="requirements">
          Must be a valid email address
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to MDN, you should try to use the `:required` and the `:invalid` pseudo-selectors, combined with the `:valid` selector.

So, when your input is required, or invalid, you can apply a style and remove it when it is valid.

Here is a working example:

```css
input[type="email"]:required,
input[type="email"]:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
  transition: ease .25s;
}

input[type="email"]:valid {
  background-color: green;
  transition: ease .25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-option">
  <input type="email" id="email" class="question-answer" placeholder=" " required>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label class="question-label" id="email-label">Email<span class="asterisk"> *</span></label>
  <div class="requirements">
    Must be a valid email address
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't quite what I'm after. I'm looking to get the input background-color  to be a certain colour only if it's invalid, but to stay there even when the user isn't focused on it, to draw attention to the fact that this field is wrong if they leave it. I've tried  `input[type="email"]:invalid {background-color: pink !important; }`
But the label goes over it when not focused and even when there's no input.